# Repeating a Sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, modular-arithmetic

Initially I have provided x and y and the value of x and y repeatedly calculated until at some point the sequence is start repeating.

```
while(x!= any previous x || y!= any previous y)
    x = (x + 7) mod (N - 1)  N is a natural number
    y = (y + 11) mod N
```

I have to tell the number of times the while loop will execute.

Sequence will be (x1,y1) (x2,y2) ..... and so on until some (xi,yi) will repeated

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $7$ does not divide $N-1$ and $11$ does not divide $N$, you have two cyclic groups.  What are their sizes?  When do you come back to the beginning?  And if one of them divides, you still have cyclic groups, but one is of size $1$.  How does that change the answer?

Comment: sir, i could not understand you ?